# Add div attributes value dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I want to add div attributes dynamically in Angular 7.

And I tried this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let e of etats._embedded.etats" 
style="background: {{e.codeCouleur}} !important;"  
data-code="{{e.id}}" data-bg={{e.codeCouleur}}>{{e.nom}"</div>
```

And I have this error:

> **Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:**
>   Can't bind to 'code' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. (" *ngFor="let e of etats._embedded.etats" style="background: {{e.codeCouleur}} !important;"  [ERROR ->]data-code="{{e.id}}" data-bg={{e.codeCouleur}}>{{e.nom}"

Comment: I'm using angular7

Comment: use this `{{e.nom}}`  instead of  `{{e.nom}"`

Comment: use ``[attr.data-code]="e.id"``  and ``[attr.data-bg]="e.codeCouleur"`` instead of ``data-code="{{e.id}}" data-bg="{{e.codeCouleur}}"``

Comment: Thanks @CruelEngine, it's works. But how can i resolve the style="..." ?

Comment: `[style.background]="e.codeCouleur"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're looping dynamically you should make use of something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let e of etats._embedded.etats" 
     [style.background]="e.codeCouleur"
     [data-code]="e.id" 
     [data-bg]=e.codeCouleur
>{{e.nom}}"</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have few options:

1. `<div attributeName="{{attributeValue}}"/></div>`
2. `<div [attr.attributeName]="attributeValue"/></div>`
3. `<div [attr.attributeName]="getAttributeValueFun()"/></div>`

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're trying to achieve is called [Attribute Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding). As the official document says:

> You must use attribute binding when there is no element property to
>   bind.

So, according to that, you need to change the code a little bit. For `style`, you can use `ngStyle` or `[style.background]`, but `!important` won't work in it:

```html
<div *ngFor="let e of etats._embedded.etats" 
  [ngStyle]="{'background': e.codeCouleur}"  
  [attr.data-code]="e.id" [attr.data-bg]="e.codeCouleur">{{e.nom}}</div>
```